# Getting data that précéde the today's date with inteval of two years

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have file with a column dates.
I want to get the dates which precede the current date with interval of two years.

I mean; we are 18/08/2021: I want all dates before 18/08/2019. of course with a dynamic date.

so tomorrow i will get all the dates before 19/08/2019

[image]

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Comment: You wants load more than 2 years old data to model? or you wants all data to load, but calculate values from more than 2 years old data?

Comment: i want all data to load, but calculate values from more than 2 years old data.
i mean from my column that contains dates from 01/01/2005 till now , i want only get data from old two years ( i want to exclue data of last two years )

Comment: You can apply filter inside DAX where it is required. Did you tried anything so far? If yes, please also share the code here.

Comment: For all your future posts Please provide sample data and expected output in a table format [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a DAX measure as following

```
Include/Exclude:= 
VAR _1 =
    DIVIDE(CONVERT ( TODAY () - MAX ( tbl[Dates] ), INTEGER )-1, 365)
VAR _2 =
    SWITCH ( TRUE (), _1 > 2, "Include", "Exclude" )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: SOlution]

Comment: Finally i have a problem. it notes this : The type CONVERT function is invalid; valid types include BOOLEAN, DOUBLE,INTEGER, DATETIME, CURRENCY, STRING.

Comment: Please provide some sample data representative of your issue and don't post pictures.

Comment: i solved the problem. thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want a `where` clause?

```
where datecol < dateadd(year, -2, convert(date, getdate()))
```